# Editing dynamically created text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

I'm creating a "social media comment section" (you can add your own comments by typing in a comment box at the bottom.) I want to add an **edit** button which can change as to what ever comment the edit button was clicked on. I am very unfamiliar with how do to do this. I've tried adding a click function that creates a text box where you can put text into but it creates the text box on every comment that has an edit button. **How can I make the "Edit" button more specific to which ever comment was clicked?**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let value;
    let storeValues = []
    let storeValueName;
    let storeValueComment;
    $('#addComment').click(function(){
    storeValueName = getName(); 
    storeValueComment = getComment();
    storeValues.push(storeValueName);
    storeValues.push(storeValueComment);
    value = getName() + getComment();
    function getName(){
        let grabName;
        $('#name').val(function(i, v){
            grabName = v;
        })
        return grabName;
    }

    function getComment(){
        let grabComment;
        $('#bodyText').val(function(i, v){
            grabComment = v;
        })
        return grabComment
    }
    console.log(storeValues);
    
    $('.eachComment').prepend('<div class="comments">' +'<img class="imgClass" src="userImage.jpg">'+'<p class="nameVal">'
    + storeValueName +'</p>' + '<p class="commentVal">'+ storeValueComment +'</p>'+
    '<input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit" />'+ '<input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete" />' + '</div>');
    
        $('#edit').click(function(){

    })
    
    })
    
})
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #E5E5E5
}



#wholeForm{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    font-family: helvetica;
}

#question{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 780px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: white;
    padding:10px;
}

#nameOfPerson{
  font-size:13px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#commentOfPerson{
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.form2{
    width: 800px;
    height: 458px;
}

.comments{
    background-color: white;
    width: 780px;
    height: 75px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}

.form1{

    padding:20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 758px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: white;
}

#addComment{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 35px;
}

#name{
    width: 125px;
}
#bodyText{
    width: 500px;
}

.formInput{
    display: inline-block;
}

.nameVal{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
}
.commentVal{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    bottom: 5px;
}

.imgClass{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 65px;
 width: 65px;
 margin: 5px;
}

#edit{
    position: absolute;
    right:55px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#30D5C8;
    background-color:white;
    margin:5px;
}

#delete{
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#30D5C8;
    background-color:white;
    margin:5px;
}

#edit:hover{
    color:#DDA0DD
}

#delete:hover{
    color:#DDA0DD
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href='style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
<div id='wholeForm'>
<div id="question">
    <p id="nameOfPerson">WhySoSerious45</p>
    <p id="commentOfPerson">Trying to decide a career path? Programming is the move. Change my mind.</p>
</div>
<div class='form2'>
    <div class='eachComment'>
    <div class="comments">
    <img class="imgClass" src="userImage.jpg">
    <p class="nameVal">Jonny R</p>
    <p class="commentVal">I wish I knew how to program! Maybe ill start learning?</p>
    <input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit">
    <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='form1'>
    <div class='formInput'>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Display Name"/>
    <input type='text' id="bodyText" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="addComment" value="Submit">
</div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-MlusDLJIP1GRgLrOflUQtshyP0TwT/RHXsI1wWGnQhs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, your site has a pretty serious security issue.  You shouldn't inject arbitrary text into HTML like that... it requires being escaped or someone can just inject any old script.  Next thing you know, they're putting stuff in that gets shown to other users and they're stealing credentials and what not.  You should be setting the *text* of elements, not just concatenating text in.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'm just creating this little project for School so its not going up on any real web pages. But I will remember this for the future. @Brad

Comment: Whether it goes up on a real site or not isn't relevant... because you're learning to do this the fundamentally wrong way.  *And*, the way you're going about it is *harder* than one of the "right" ways.  Is some teacher teaching you this way?  If so, they're flat out wrong.  I'll see if I can write some code to steer you in a direction, one moment.

Comment: Actually, since you have quite a bit to this template, you're probably better off using something built for it like Lit.  https://lit.dev/  Even if you want to just use its `html` function, that's available as its own module:  https://lit.dev/docs/libraries/standalone-templates/

Comment: Some other notes to consider as you continue to learn that will probably save you a lot of hassle...  There really is no need for jQuery these days.  Back in the day, we needed it just to standardize across several APIs, especially things like selecting elements or making AJAX requests... but now `Element.querySelector()` works uniformly, and the Fetch API exists.  For your CSS, consider *not* hardcoding sizes like this.  If you do set a size, you can make it relative to other items by using `em` dimensions and what not.

Comment: On positioning... check out CSS Flexbox and Grid.  You can lay out your page in a way you want that will work well on a variety of devices, regardless of pixel dimension.  And, *it's easier*!

Comment: Element IDs... generally you should avoid these because they clutter up the global namespace in JavaScript.  This is a holdover from back in the day when these sort of IDs were needed for speed, and as the only universal way to access the elements.  Today, this is not required.

Comment: you are explanation is so much, can you tell in shortly , what exactly want

Comment: Gotcha this makes alot of sense. @Brad

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI We are both named Brad so it looks like I am posting a lot haha. The question is "How can I make an edit button edit dynamically created text"

Comment: do you want any validation , while sending comment, like minimum character should 20, OR after send comment input textbox should blank

Comment: yeah minimum 20 characters would be nice! @MAYURSANCHETI

Comment: @Brad See this:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation  Doing it in a standard way helps screen readers and other assistants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in a general sense…

When you add an event listener, the specific element will show up on the event's `target` property.  So, if we had something like this:

```
<div class="posts">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

We could actually add a `click` handler to the div, because [events "bubble"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) up to it.

```
document.querySelector('.posts').addEventListener('click' (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.textContent); // Button 1, Button 2, etc.
});
```

Comment: Hey @Brad i've been looking over some of the things you sent me for this question. I just have some questions about what you said. Is there a better for me to ask these questions to you like a chat box? Im new to stack overflow and I don't see a way to message you other than tagging you in a comment.

Comment: @Brad On Stack Overflow, it's good to post a new question for each topic.  I'd be happy to answer them.  Though, if you have any clarifications for something I said specifically, I can answer them in comments or you can e-mail me at brad@musatcha.com.